# formatting js functions, missing

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have some missing closing tags, but I'm can't really find why is not well formatted, any suggestions? they are just two functions close and open:

```
 open: function() {
                $('#Form').hide();
                $('body').css('height', 'auto');
                $modal.parent().css({ 'width': 'auto', 'left': '0', 'right': '0', 'top': '0', 'box-shadow': 'none' });
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                dialogOpened();

            };

            close: function() {
                $('#Form').show();
                if(originalHeightCss)
                    $('body').css('height', originalHeightCss);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                if(isOk) {
                    window.dnnModal.closePopUp(refresh, closingUrl);
                }else{
                    window.location.href = '/default.aspx?ctl=logoff'
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: ... Is this supposed to be an object with `open` and `close` keys? I mean, start there--if so, they should be separated with a comma, not a semicolon. Then there's the extra braces, and possibly an extra paren, depending on what you're actually doing. Consider something like http://jsbeautifier.org/, or just pay more attention.

Comment: What are you using for formatting?  What tags are you talking about?

Comment: I like my answer but I think I may have misunderstood the question. if he's asking why close is indented so much that's definitely a formatter question and not enough information provided.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just defining Javascript functions, first of all your function declaration should be of the form:

```
function close() {
```

and not

```
close: function() {
```

If I fix the function declaration and remove the last two lines (bracket, paren, bracket) then it is valid javascript.

Dave's recommendation of http://jsbeautifier.org/ is solid, though I would go one step further and suggest using an IDE capable of catching these issues like Visual Studio or NetBeans.